# How to detect swipes up in Gesture Detector?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I know for swipe down detection there is `onVerticalDragDown` but for swipe up detection there is no `onVerticalDragUp` parameter in `GestureDetector` widget.

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55850504/7652758

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for ***onPanUpdate*** method in GestureDetector class.

```
GestureDetector(onPanUpdate: (details) {
  if (details.delta.dx > 0)
    print("Dragging in +X direction");
  else
    print("Dragging in -X direction");

  if (details.delta.dy > 0)
    print("Dragging in +Y direction");
  else
    print("Dragging in -Y direction");
});
```

Note: Do not use this method with the ones that you are already using (onVerticalDragDown) or onVerticalDragUpdate().